# Getting the username of SystemUser in a C# console application (Dynamics CRM)

Tags: dynamics-crm

**Is there a way to get the username (or Fullname or anything of off SystemUser) in a regular C# console application?**

If I do a WhoAmIRequest and then use the UserId to Retrieve "SystemUserEntity" from OrganizationService, it says that there's no entity with the name 'SystemUser'.

If I try to make a GET request with that UserId to the OData REST endpoint (for example: *http://localhost:8081/TestOrg/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserSet(guid'58a30c1a-3730-e511-80c8-080027c078bd'*), I keep getting 401 forbidden, although if I simply paste that link into my browser, I get all of the info I need. As far as I understand, that is because I have authentification when using my browser.

So, another possible question would be "how to get correct authentification in a C# Console Application to talk to the OData REST endpoint".

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to use SOAP instead of OData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieving the fullname once you have the user id works like this:

```
// guid userId = ...
var username = service.Retrieve("systemuser", userId, new ColumnSet("fullname")).GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname");
```

Caveat being, you have to use the logical names (all lowercase) instead of the schema (capitalized) name, i.e. `systemuser` instead of `SystemUser`

Comment: thanks. I made a typing-without-thinking mistake.
var response = service.Retrieve("SystemUser", UsersGuid, new ColumnSet("fullname")); 
 That's why it said that there's no such entity.